# Android Intent in public function

Tags: java, android, function, android-intent

Hi i am trying to make a public function in order to change activities/changes in my android application.

In a external class (Utl.java) I have this code.

```
public class Utl extends Activity{
public void onBtnClicked(View v) {
    Intent i;
    Integer data=0;

    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnStart:
            i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LevelChoose.class);                   
            startActivity(i);
        break;
        case R.id.btnEasy:
            i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayGame.class);
            startActivity(i);
        break;
        case R.id.btnMedium:
            i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayGame.class);
            data=48;
            i.putExtra("extra", data);
            startActivity(i);
        break;
        case R.id.btnHard:
            i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayGame.class);
            data=96;
            i.putExtra("extra", data);
            startActivity(i);
        break;
        }

    }
}
```

and in my xml's files i use the on click function of the buttons...

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:minHeight="110dp"
    android:text="Start Game"
    android:onClick="cls2.onBtnClicked(this)" />
```

I get that the function can't be found...

I wish to dynamically change screens.... Thank you for your time!!

Comment: where is `onCreate` for the activity?

Comment: you need to chnge like *android:onClick="onBtnClicked"* and add overridden onCreate method to Actvt

Comment: If this is not an actual `Activity` then you shouldn't be extending it. Because it sounds to me like that's what is going on. Can you explain a little better what you are doing?

Comment: I have three screens. my first screen has a button which, when clicked the user moves to the second screen. On the second screen there are three more buttons(options for the user). Buttons of the second screen lead to the third after clicked. At first i used setOnClicklistenter for each button but i wished to make it more simple but adding a function so it can be done without adding the id of the buttons every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the constructor where you can assign the current context. Try this example

```
public void sampleMethod(final Activity cont)
{
Intent intent = new Intent(cont, XYZ.class);
        cont.finish();
        cont.startActivity(intent);
}
```

also move this method to a util class and call it from activity and pass the activity reference as follows

```
class ActivityB extends Activity
{
  Util.sampleMethod(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues in your code. I'll try to list them here:

1. You cannot pass a method of any class to android:onClick.

   You'll have to set the onClickListener for your `Buttons` in code, using

   ```
   yourButton.setOnClickListener(new Utl());
   ```
2. Don't make Utl a subclass of `Activity`. Use `Activity` only for different "screens". You'll want to use `Object` instead here. If you need a `Context` in Utl, add a class member and take a Context in the constructor, like this:

   ```
   private Context mContext;

   public Utls (Context c){
       mContext = c;
   }
   ```

   Now, instantiate Utls like this:

   ```
   yourButton.setOnClickListener(new Utl(this));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line

```
android:onClick="cls2.onBtnClicked(this)"
```

to

```
android:onClick="onBtnClicked"
```

View will be passed to function automatically.

Happy coding..:)